# How to select Item from drop down in gwtbootstrap

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I am using gwtbootstarp3 with ui-binder and gwt. I am unable to select the item from the dropdown and update the text pf the main button. 
http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#buttonDropdowns

Please help me how can I achieve that.

**Update**

here is my code

```
 <b:ListDropDown>
                 <b:AnchorButton dataToggle="DROPDOWN" ui:field="searchBy" text="Search By"></b:AnchorButton>
                 <b:DropDownMenu>
                    <b:AnchorListItem ui:field="searchByTitle" text="Title"></b:AnchorListItem>
                    <b:AnchorListItem ui:field="searchByAuthor" text="Author"></b:AnchorListItem>
                    <b:AnchorListItem ui:field="searchByCategory" text="Category"></b:AnchorListItem>
                 </b:DropDownMenu>
              </b:ListDropDown>
```

Currently I am writing Clickevent on individual item but it would be nice if I can have one event on `ListDropDown`

Comment: What do you mean you can't select the item? It doesn't fire a `ClickEvent`? Can you post the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you'd expect the event on the `ListDropDown` be, but maybe in this particular case, using [Select](http://gwtbootstrap3.github.io/gwtbootstrap3-demo/#select) would be a better choice? From the user's point of view, it behaves a lot like a dropdown.

Otherwise, you're stuck with `ClickHandler`s on individual items and then updating the `ListDropDown` manually. I don't know the whole use case, but remember that you can use the same `ClickHandler` among widgets - either the same instance or class, depending on your needs.